# Detect user from mobile or desktop wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a wordpress website which is having responsive theme. I have a small task now and i am confused how to achieve it.

I want to disable the header ad if the user is browsing from mobile devices. I achieved it by a custom CSS.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 670px) {
.header-ads {display:none !important;}
}
```

but now i am having difficulty. i would like to show that ad somewhere else. So disabling the ad from header is okay. but what should be the if condition in PHP of wordpress where i can write to show my ad if the user-agent is mobile

can anyone write for me the if condition

```
<?php advman_ad('header-ad-for-mobile'); ?>
```

this is the code i want to add in the if condition

if user=from mobile

```
<?php advman_ad('header-ad-for-mobile'); ?>
```

end if

i have seen someone said it can be achieved by the following code

```
<?php
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
header('Location: http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');
?>
```

but the above code looks obsolete. it was publish on 2014.

Thanks
Naaz

Comment: http://mobiledetect.net

Comment: can't you just use the `viewport?` and set the screen resolution to add a new `clickable` button or link to view that ad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 670px) {
    .header-ads {display:none !important;}
}
```

Isn't actually disabling the ad but instead hiding it via CSS. As such, you'll also need to add your code in for the mobile ad by using **advman_ad('header-ad-for-mobile');** but then you'll have to do the following:

```
.mobile-header-ads {display:hide;}

@media only screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 670px) {
    .header-ads {display:none !important;}
    .mobile-header-ads {display:show !important;}
}
```

This will hide the mobile ad on desktop and force it to be shown on mobile. However, on every page load you'll be getting 2 ads loaded, even though only 1 will ever be shown, it's not an issue but something to consider. (change the mobile css selector to whatever it is)

Comment: Thanks Garry for the prompt reply and i am so sorry for my limited knowledge about PHP and wordpress. Can you please explain a bit how to do step by step. i am putting that code of css in custom css field.